# NuGet interop pacakge guidelines around Debug and Release builds

Tags: .net, c++-cli, nuget, native, mixed-mode

I'm creating a NuGet package written in C++/CLI. It serves as an interop between C# and native C++.

The produced DLL has a managed surface area, and a native implib surface area.

Visual Studio only likes to consume a single reference assembly from a NuGet package, not a different reference assembly per Debug or Release configuration of the receiving project.

I want the reference assembly consumed from the NuGet package to differ according to configuration, so that I can embed both a Debug and Release DLL in the nupkg and have Release C# builds bind to the Release DLL and Debug C# builds bind to the Debug DLL.

This is a requirement for me because it appears that the native binary object layout of std C++ classes (std::string, for example) is differing between my Debug and Release builds.

The Release compile of the DLL is failing to work with the Debug compile of the rest of the program. I get similar failure with the Debug compiles of the DLL and Release compiles of the program.

Is there anything I can do here? I've done a little exploring of putting the reference elements in the NuGet .props or .targets file, and using the $(Configuration) property, but I haven't gotten that to work yet.

Comment: Hardly the only problem, you get the exact same matching problems when the library user has a different VS version.  This should *never* be an issue in a C++/CLI project, you are exposing only the managed interface.  What your C++ code looks like must always be an implementation detail so it doesn't matter at all that you deploy the Release build version.

Answer (score 1):

I may have just gotten this to work, although I will admit I'm not sure how well this will translate to a real world project.

My interop NuGet package:

1. Embeds both debug and release DLLs in lib\native\debug\ and lib\native\release\ respectively.
2. Has a .props file that contains an `<ItemGroup><Reference>` to the DLL, along with a `<HintPath>` to `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\lib\native\$(Configuration)\[DLL Name]`

This was able to successfully bind to Debug or Release NuGet DLL, dependent upon the build configuration.